# Unsupported major.minor version java as windows service with procrun

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services, procrun

I am trying to run my java application as a windows service.
I did as said here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090228071059/http://blog.platinumsolutions.com/node/234

and http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html

And I get this exception:

```
  2013-02-04 14:52:25 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: serviceWrapper : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
      at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  Exception in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your default JRE, installed on your Windows is 1.6 or less, while classes, which you are trying to run, are compiled under Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime.

The version number shown describes the version of the JRE that the class file is compatible with.

```
J2SE 7 = 51,
J2SE 6.0 = 50,
J2SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application is a Java 7 application, but it looks like you have Java 6 (or less). You can install Java 7 on [the Java website](http://java.com).

Answer (score 0):

This exception says that the JRE you are running on is Java 6.0 or an earlier version, but the classes you are trying to run (or at least some of them) have been compiled using a Java 7.0 compiler.

There are two approaches to solving this:

- Upgrade your execution platform to Java 7.0, and your code should run as-is.
- Recompile your code for the Java 6.0 (or earlier) platform:

  - Install a Java 6.0 (or older) JDK and recompile your code.
  - Compile your code using your existing Java 7.0 build environment, but using suitable "-target" and "-bootclasspath" options to get the compiler to generate Java 6.0 compatible code.

(I would recommend an upgrade ...)